# How to send my app in foreground after a Facetime (integrated) call?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, multitasking, facetime

I'm trying to integrate Facetime in my app so basically what I would like to do is to press a button making a call and when it finishes come back to my app. I know that for the time being there are no public API for Facetime.

What I'm doing at the moment is to use Facetime scheme:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"facetime://"]];
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use in the openURL above the string "facetime://" in order to choose who I want to call in Facetime?! I tried it but what happens is that Facetime is run but without its layout so basically I see myself on the screen but I cannot do nothing.
2. If not point 1 therefore I use for example "facetime://steve@apple.com" is it possible to come back to my app once the call is finish?! I read about multitasking but I don't know how to manage it in this situation.

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Hi Alex did you get the solution to your second question?I too need this.

Comment: @Tendulkar I didn't. I guess it is still not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anser your second question, NO just like when your app start a call there is no way to get your app back in the foreground after you close the call.

For your first question, you need to add the contact data (e-mail or phonenumber).

Also be aware that the `facetime://` url scheme will work on any iPhone/iPod Touch even if they can't do facetime. If the device does not have facetime support it will just show a blank screen.

Comment: You can get back to the app after a phone call, using "telprompt:" instead of "tel:". Another way for phone calls is to use a UIWebView to execute the link - that gives the same result as "telprompt:". There does not seem to be a similar solution for Facetime though. :-(